# "of" Vs "at" is it something idiomatic or there is a grammartical rule?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions, vocabulary, prepositional-phrases

What is the rule that I can follow to decide when to use "of" or "at"
When they are both used for causes.

1- I'm ( surprised/amazed/disappointed) at you.

2- I'm (afraid/sick/tired ) of  you.

Comment: Ii's often "I'm happy with ...." And certainly 'bored with'. You have to be around practised Anglophones to pick up what's idiomatic. And/or read lots of good literature. But here, note that 'alarmed at' contrasts with 'afraid of'; note that one addresses a more punctive (rather than durative) causal agent. 'Afraid of dying'. 'Alarmed at the sudden increase in deaths'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth   Thank you for the information, but actually I don't  totally understand what you mean by  "punctive" and "durative" . Could you please give some more details ??

Comment: You are usually 'alarmed at/by something' and almost always 'startled by' something within a brief timespan rather than over say hours or weeks. An event that is 'momentary' (not necessarily as brief as an instant, but over some brief timespan within an ongoing period) is punctive. The continuous/lasting situation / activity is durative.